# C++ SQL Queries/SQL Wrapped for C++?

Tags: c++, sql, c, oracle, wrapper

Just more a general question I can't seem to find a definite answer on.
But what is a good SQL wrapper for C++ that allows me to call queries?
I'm used to Oracle, but i've used MYSQL before aswell.

And how would you call something such as an insert statement (for example) in one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I love [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/), simple and easy to use, just follow the link for easy example code and a much better explanation of what SOCI is all about then I could put in this answer. I use this for all of my C++ SQL development work.

Comment: Oh Wow Nice, it supports all three common ones. Good find!

Comment: @Matt Smith: From memory, it also supports sqlite if you compile it from source and add that flag in. I like sqlite for small projects so I have compiled it from source and it is a pretty simple process. (Not only that but it is packaged for Ubuntu if you use Linux)